# jquery mobile link causing page to jump to bottom of page

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile

wonder if anyone can help me. I am developing an app in phone gap using Jquery mobile, I'm having an issue that what theres a hyperlink in the text which is below the 'fold' of the iphone screen the page jumps to the bottom half of the screen.

Has anyone has this problem?
Do I need to wrap the link in a div or something, its really annoying me now :-)

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

At a guess without seeing your code, I assume your link looks something like this:

```
<a href="#otherDivID">click me</a>
```

In which case, in the click handler for this element should have `preventDefault()` added to it, like this:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do stuff
});
```